# Prevent keypress method to be called multiple times when enter key held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am making a simple search bar using the HTML input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="search_bar" />
```

Then in jQuery I implement the keypress method to detect when the user hits the enter/return key:

```
$('#search_bar').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) { // enter/return
        e.preventDefault();
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

However, if the user decides the hold down the enter key, this method will be called multiple times. I want to disable this behavior, i.e. `keypress` only called once when the user hits enter but not called again when the key is held down. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: try using the onkeyup method instead http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 5):

Using `onkeyup()` will only detect when the key has been released. This should solve your holding enter problem.

```
$('#search_bar').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) { // enter/return
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("xx");
    }
});
```

Hold down enter -- xx is only logged on the release.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veRkd/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `keydown` or `keyup`. That will probably change the `keycode` value.

Comment: `onkeyup` is the traditional behaviour for detecting keypresses

Comment: When a key is held, the keydown event is fired multiple times. Only the keyup event is fired once

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timer since what you are experiencing is the behavior of `keypress` (`keyup` and `keydown` could be used for counting the key presses but it will probably be rather tricky to track all [edge cases on all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)).

```
$('#search_bar').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) { // enter/return
        e.preventDefault();

        if (window.preventDuplicateKeyPresses)
            return;

        window.preventDuplicateKeyPresses = true;
        window.setTimeout(function() { window.preventDuplicateKeyPresses = false; }, 500 );

        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer helped me in vue problem.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is bit late to answer above question. But I would suggest to [create a debounce function.](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) The function will only fire once every fraction of a second instead of as quickly as it's triggered. It surely helps to boost the performance incredibly.

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var apiRequestFunction = debounce(function() {
 //send an AJAX network request.
 //250 indicates the minimum time interval between the series of events being fired
}, 250);

$('#search_bar').keypress(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //do stuff
        //Function call to send an AJAX network request
        apiRequestFunction();
});
```

[Reference blogpost by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try using either the [Keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or [Keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead. They're only fired in the event of the key changing from one state to the other.